# Handling a delayed response of a Token

Tags: angularjs, keycloak

I was trying to create an improved login example from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/demo-template/angular-product-app
Something that seems more adaptable for beginners.

Anyway, I added all the initial configuration in a providers and a config, as I felt is a better angular approach.
Then I tried to call keycloak.init(), which is a function that initialize the variables and according to the params you pass on it you can see if it is already logged.
The problem is that when it is logged the token takes a while, which I guess is normal.

So I added a $rootScope.watch(loggedIn) so when the init() has succeded it $rootScope.loggedIn is set to true, and if it changes.

I added a $scope.$apply inside $rootScope.$watch.
As the code is right now, it works, I get a $diggest problem because of the $scope.$apply but it works. I know this is really buggy.

So I am looking for a solution. I am really new to angular. I can think only on the following ways around it

1) One that could work without $rootScope, I think it would be a much nicer code if it worked without $rootScope, but I am not sure how.  Maybe using promises, $q,etc.
2) Using $timeout, I am still reading on this.

I am looking for a more angularjs elegant solution.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


    app.controller('PageController', function($rootScope,$scope, $http ,keycloakLauncher) {

        $scope.loggedIn = keycloakLauncher.loggedIn;

        $scope.user = function(){
            console.log("keycloak ", keycloakLauncher.keycloak);
            console.log("loggedin ", keycloakLauncher.loggedIn);
            if($scope.loggedIn){
                /*if(keycloakLauncher.keycloak.idTokenParsed == undefined){
                    return "Anonymous"
                }*/
                return keycloakLauncher.keycloak.idTokenParsed.email
            }

            return "Anonymous";
        };

        $scope.products = [];
        $scope.reloadData = function() {
            $http.get("https://localhost:8443/unika/usuarios").success(function(data) {
                $scope.products = angular.fromJson(data);

            });

        };

        $scope.logout = function(){
            console.log('*** LOGOUT');
            keycloakLauncher.loggedIn = false;
            keycloakLauncher.keycloak = null;
            window.location = keycloakLauncher.logoutUrl;
        };
        $scope.login = function () {
            console.log('*** LOGIN');
            keycloakLauncher.keycloak.login();
        };

        $rootScope.$watch('loggedIn', function(){
            $scope.loggedIn = keycloakLauncher.loggedIn;
            $scope.user();
            $scope.$apply();
        });

    });

    app.provider('keycloakLauncher', function keycloakLauncherProvider() {
        this.keycloak = {};
        this.loggedIn = false;
        this.logoutUrl = "/";

        this.$get =  function () {
            var keycloak = this.keycloak;
            var loggedIn = this.loggedIn;
            //var logoutUrl
            return {
                keycloak: keycloak,
                loggedIn: loggedIn,
                logoutUrl: this.logoutUrl
            };
        };
    });

    app.factory('authInterceptor', function($q, keycloakLauncher) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var keycloak = keycloakLauncher.keycloak;
                console.log("authint", keycloakLauncher.loggedIn);
                if (keycloak.token) {
                    keycloak.updateToken(5).success(function() {
                        config.headers = config.headers || {};
                        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token;

                        deferred.resolve(config);
                    }).error(function() {
                        deferred.reject('Failed to refresh token');
                    });
                }
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    });

    app.factory('errorInterceptor', function($q) {
        return function(promise) {
            return promise.then(function(response) {
                return response;
            }, function(response) {
                if (response.status == 401) {
                    console.log('session timeout?');
                    logout();
                } else if (response.status == 403) {
                    alert("Forbidden");
                } else if (response.status == 404) {
                    alert("Not found");
                } else if (response.status) {
                    if (response.data && response.data.errorMessage) {
                        alert(response.data.errorMessage);
                    } else {
                        alert("An unexpected server error has occurred");
                    }
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
    });

    app.config(function($httpProvider, keycloakLauncherProvider) {
        keycloakLauncherProvider.keycloak = new Keycloak('WEB-INF/keycloak.json');
        keycloakLauncherProvider.logoutUrl = "https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/unika/tokens/logout?redirect_uri=http://unika.localdomain/index2.html";
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    });


    app.run(['keycloakLauncher','$rootScope',function(keycloakLauncher,$rootScope) {
        console.log("runner")
        $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
        keycloakLauncher.keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso' }).success(function () {
            console.log("entro");
            keycloakLauncher.loggedIn = keycloakLauncher.keycloak.authenticated;
            console.log("login", keycloakLauncher.loggedIn);
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
        }).error(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        });

    }]);
```